# Properly implement concurrency control in ASP.NET WebAPI + SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, concurrency

I'm writing a very simple web application that serves as an endpoint for uploading money transactions from customers and saving them in SQL Server DB. It accepts requests with just 2 params: `userid: 'xxx', balancechange: -19.99`. If the user ID exists in the app database, then the balance is changed; if not - a new row is created for this ID.

The difficult part in all this is that the numer of requests is enormous and I have to implement the app in such a way that it works as fast as possible and resolves concurrency issues (if 2 requests for the same ID arrive simultaneously).

The app is a ASP.NET MVC WebAPI. I chose to use plain old ADO.NET for speed, and this is what I currently have:

```
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
public void UpdateBalance(string userId, decimal balance)
{
    lock (syncLock)
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Id = '{userId}'", sqlConnection);
            if ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
            {
                command = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO Users (Id, Balance) VALUES ('{userId}', 0)", sqlConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            command = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE Users SET Balance = Balance + {balance} WHERE Id = {userId}", sqlConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Called from a controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateBalance(string id, decimal balanceChange)
{
    UpdateBalance(id, balanceChange);
    return Ok();
}
```

The thing I'm concernred with is concurrency control using `lock (syncLock)`. This would slow the app down under high load and doesn't allow multiple instances of the app to be deployed on different servers. What are ways to properly implement concurrency control here?

Note: I'd like to use a fast and DB-independent way of implementing concurrency control, as the current storage mechanism (SQL Server) can change in the future.

Comment: Addition is Associative, so why are you concerned with a change in balance being done in order? And if you want more speed you should encapsulate that in a stored procedure instead of inline (injection prone) strings.

Comment: your SQL code is open for SQL injections since the `userId` variable is a string. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Your locks must be per row and distributed: you need a DB transaction. I do not understand why you are trying to re-implement it using a brittle approach like that one.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I'm concerned about the 'INSERT INTO' part. If 2 requests with the same ID that doesnt exist in the DB yet arrive simultaneously, the code  without locks might try to insert it twice.

Comment: That's why you need a transaction. You can wrap your code in a TransactionScope or use a stored procedure with a transaction.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma, I'd be greatful if you could show me the DB-independent code implementing the necessary transactions here. I'm quite new to SQL concurrency issues, so forgive me if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

First, DB-independent code:

For this, you will want to look at [DbProviderFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z(v=vs.110).aspx). What this allows is passing the provider name (`MySql.Data.MySqlClient`, `System.Data.SqlClient`), then using the abstract classes (`DbConnection`, `DbCommand`) you interact with your DB.

Second, using transactions and paramaterized queries:

When you are working with a database, you ALWAYS want to have your queries paramaterized. If you use `String.Format()` or any other type of string concatenation, you open your query up to injection.

Transactions ensure all or nothing with your queries, and they can also lock down the table so that only queries within the transaction can access those tables. Transactions have two commands, `Commit` which will save the changes (if any) to the DB, and `Rollback` which discards any changes to the DB.

The following will assume that you already have an instance of `DbProviderFactory` in a class variable `_factory`.

```
public void UpdateBalance(string userId, decimal balanceChange)
{
    //since we might need to execute two queries, we will create the paramaters once
    List<DbParamater> paramaters = new List<DbParamater>();
    DbParamater userParam = _factory.CreateParamater();
    userParam.ParamaterName = "@userId";
    userParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
    userParam.Value = userId;
    paramaters.Add(userParam);

    DbParamater balanceChangeParam = _factory.CreateParamater();
    balanceChangeParam.ParamaterName = "@balanceChange";
    balanceChangeParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Decimal;
    balanceChangeParam.Value = balanceChange;
    paramaters.Add(balanceChangeParam);

    //Improvement: if you implement a method to clone a DbParamater, you can
    //create the above list in class construction instead of function invocation 
    //then clone the objects for the function.

    using (DbConnection conn = _factory.CreateConnection()){
        conn.Open(); //Need to open the connection before you start the transaction
        DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
        //IsolationLevel.Serializable locks the entire table down until the
        //transaction is commited or rolled back.

        try {
            int changedRowCount = 0;

            //We can use the fact that ExecuteNonQuery will return the number
            //of affected rows, and if there are no affected rows, a 
            //record does not exist for the userId.
            using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()){
                cmd.Transaction = trans; //Need to set the transaction on the command
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Balance = Balance + @balanceChange WHERE Id = @userId";
                cmd.Paramaters.AddRange(paramaters.ToArray());
                changedRowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            if(changedRowCount == 0){
                //If no record was affected in the previous query, insert a record
                using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()){
                    cmd.Transaction = trans; //Need to set the transaction on the command
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Id, Balance) VALUES (@userId, @balanceChange)";
                    cmd.Paramaters.AddRange(paramaters.ToArray());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            trans.Commit(); //This will persist the data to the DB.
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            trans.Rollback(); //This will cause the data NOT to be saved to the DB.
                              //This is the default action if Commit is not called.
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            trans.Dispose(); //Need to call dispose
        }

        //Improvement: you can remove the try-catch-finally block by wrapping 
        //the conn.BeginTransaction() line in a using block. I used a try-catch here
        //so that you can more easily see what is happening with the transaction.
    }
}
```